# How to find payment collection using response id?

Tags: mongodb

I am developing angularjs nodejs application

Following has Payment Collection find function and result

```
var collectionId = "5673d6c7da28e94f51277894"

Payment.find({id: collectionId}).exec(function(err,payment)
      console.log(payment);
);
```

Console result :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5673d6c7da28e94f51277894"),
    "response" : {
        "status" : "approved",
        "id" : "PAY-9N740711P28316116KZX5U4I"
    }
}
```

I need to find payment collection using response id

My code here

```
var paymentId = "PAY-9N740711P28316116KZX5U4I"

Payment.find({ response : {id: paymentId}}).exec(function(err,payment)
      console.log(payment);
);
```

Console result :

```
undefined
```

If you are not clear question, please comment

Hope answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
Payment.find({ 'response.id': paymentId }).exec(function(err,payment) {
      console.log(payment);
});
```

Comment: I got this error   :    
     Payment.find( {response.id : paymentId}).exec(function(err,payment){
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)

Comment: Sorry: `{'response.id' : orderId}` add quotes

Comment: Payment.find( {response.id : paymentId}).exec(function(err,payment){ ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token . at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16) at Module._compile (module.js:413:25) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)

Comment: You missed also the `{}` in the callback `(function(err,payment) { // do something });`. Answer updated. Copy and paste it.